# Assign Rank to Row based on Alphabetical Order Using Window Functions in PySpark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I'm trying to assign a rank to the rows of a dataframe using a window function over a string column (user_id), based on alphabetical order. So, for example:

```
user_id | rank_num
-------------------
A       |1
A       |1
A       |1
B       |2
A       |1
B       |2
C       |3
B       |2
B       |2
C       |3
```

I tried using the following lines of code:

```
user_window = Window().partitionBy('user_id').orderBy('user_id')
data = (data
       .withColumn('profile_row_num', dense_rank().over(user_window))
)
```

But I'm getting something like:

```
user_id | rank_num
-------------------
A       |1
A       |1
A       |1
B       |1
A       |1
B       |1
C       |1
B       |1
B       |1
C       |1
```

Comment: @blackbishop Issue was solved below, precisely because of the error of adding an the partitionBy method to the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partition by `user_id` is unnecessary. This will cause all `user_id` to fall into their own partition and get a rank of 1. The code below should do what you wanted:

```
user_window = Window.orderBy('user_id')
data = data.withColumn('profile_row_num', dense_rank().over(user_window))
```